# Does "arm_navigation stack on the Barrett WAM" work on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Running%20the%20arm_navigation%20stack%20on%20the%20Barrett%20WAM%20%28Fuerte%29

Tutorial is for Fuerte and Fuerte  just works on older systems...

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267377/does-%22arm_navigation-stack-on-the-barrett-wam%22-work-on-ubuntu-16.04?/) by [loo a](https://answers.ros.org/users/31344/loo-a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. According to the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/arm_navigation#Note) this has been deprecated since Groovy and the functionality has been moved into the MoveIt! package and ROS Groovy is only supported until [Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal)](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#groovy-galapagos-oct-2012).

> Starting with ROS Groovy this stack is
> deprecated. Replacement functionality
> is now part of [MoveIt!](http://moveit.ros.org/)

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [loo a](https://answers.ros.org/users/31344/loo-a/) on 2017-07-26**:
Thank you! Started using MoveIt

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-26**:
If this is the correct answer please mark it as correct.